# How to modify a XML element

Tags: html, xml, web-services, unix, kernel

I have a XML document file, and I want to do some changes or you can be say I want to change the values in these elements. But in this XML document there are some element which I can't understand means How can I change them. A sample code is here, Please see and let me know about that highlighted code, what is that type of code and how can i place my value in it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <ServerConfig>
 <rootLevel>ASIS</rootLevel>
 <svpath>$../root/CMP/</svpath>
 <vardes>Cobol</vardes>
 <uname>root</uname>
 <pname>ls_All</pname>
 <param/> <!-- How can i edit this value and what is this, this type of element I have never seen before --> 
 </ServerConfig>
```

Please let me know about what type of this **< param/>** element in this xml and how can i change the value for it

Comment: Did you try using getElementById method?

Comment: It's not JAVASCRIPT, first should be check the question and then respond about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think `<param>` means parameter.
You can change/set the value like this:

```
<param>yourValue</param>
```

Comment: It's doesn't work for me, I think there is something other mean of this kind of element. and may be some different way to set the value in it.

Comment: There is also an error in the XML syntax: <rootLevel> has no closing tag, maybe this is the problem..?!

Comment: In the original code there is not such type of issue, I just write a sample code from there, It is not that absolute code. the issue is just in that <param/>, I couldn't write my value in it, The system doesn't parsing it to the server configuration.